# Unable to access CA after renaming server

Tags: 2013, farm, psconfig

I have a single server SharePoint 2013 VM. (SharePoint and SQL installed on one machine).

I made a copy of VM and then renamed the host name from OldServer to NewServer. I am able to access SQL Server from Management Studio using name NewServer.

Then I renamed it using STSADM which showed success message.

```
stsadm -o renameserver -oldservername OldServer -newservername NewServer
```

I restarted machine and now after that I am unable to access SharePoint.

If I open CA on new URL `http://NewServer:43456` then I get following error message.

> This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a
>   server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from
>   the configuration database. To connect this server to the server farm,
>   use the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, located on the Start
>   menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products.

If I open Powershell then I get following error message:

> The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are
>   not registered.

If I try to run Products Configuration Wizard then I get following message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found

And Wizard doesn't show me any option to disconnect server from farm and then rejoin (probably because it is single server?)

SQL Server is up and running and I can connect to it using both Named Pipes and TCPIP. Named Pipes is enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager. Both new and old farms are part of same AD and no change has been made in service/farm accounts.

What to do now?

Comment: See if this helps http://joelblogs.co.uk/2011/10/23/renaming-a-standalone-sharepoint-2010-server/

Comment: I have already performed steps mentioned in this link.

Comment: This sounds as though the 'farm' was not configured using the 'standalone' option, and therefore there is an issue insofar as SharePoint's configuration is still pointing to the OldServer for its SQL connection. Have you tried creating a SQL alias using 'cliconfg' that points 'OldServer' -> NewServer and then trying again? This should redirect all SQL connections to 'NewServer' even though the configuration settings for SharePoint all point to 'OldServer' for the SQL connections.

Comment: I have already tried using alias but same problem. I even stopped the SQL Server service to see if it shows any different message but it shows same error which means it is not been able to communicate with it.

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot from your configured alias in cliconfg?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/j9c4X

I have done this in both 32 and 64 bit cliconfg. Also tried with namedpipes.